# WebRequest.GetRequestStream and LOH

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I am using code below to upload large file to server and noticed that copying FileStream to GetRequestStream the bytes array is created and hold in memory. This increase large object heap and I don't want it. Maybe someone know how to solve this?

```
Stream formData = new FileStream(.....)

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {             
     Helpers.CopyStream(formData, requestStream);
     requestStream.Close();
    }

     public static void CopyStream(Stream fromStream, Stream toStream)
            {
                try
                {
                    int bytesRead;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                    while (fromStream != null && (bytesRead = fromStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        toStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    //suppress empty stream response
                }
            }
```

Memory profiler graph. bytes array create internally in GetRequestStream

[image: Memory profiler graph. bytes array create internally in GetRequestStream]

Comment: Is that bytes array the one you passed to it, or an internal instance of the request stream?

Comment: The byte array is the same size as my passed file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowwritestreambuffering.aspx) to disable internal buffering:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

    using (Stream formData = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        formData.CopyTo(requestStream, 32768);
    }
```

Comment: Do not makes any difference, still problem with large objects. If you will look at memory profiler graph you will find that Bytes array is created after copying a stream.

Comment: I think I found a solution: `HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering`... MSDN says the default is true. You can disable it a see what happens.

Comment: Please remove code about copying stream, this is not related with the problem and Flush is not needed while copying stream. Tested!