# Upload Big File by c# thread

Tags: c#, file-upload

I have a function `uploadfile()` and in this function I upload a file in chunks:

```
Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream();
byte[] bufferUploadSize = new byte[4096];//ex.
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bufferUploadSize,0, bufferUploadSize.Length)) != 0)
{
    writer.Write(bufferUploadSize, 0, bytesRead);
}
fileStream.Close();
```

I did it with no error but when I watch my program in Windows Task Manager I realize that memory used by my program increases until the size of file.  For example, when I upload a 1GB file memory increases little by little until 1GB.  Why?

Can I change the code to use just, for example, 40KB instead of 1GB RAM?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052679/webrequest-getrequeststream-and-loh

Comment: run a profiler on your code and see where the memory is coming from, see what objects you're hodling onto references to that you shouldn't have, look for disposable objects that you're not disposing of (I see one  in the code sample you posted), etc.

Comment: thanks every body i solve it i must use allow buffer =false before of requset.getstream and my problem solved,thanks for you and i wish good moment with your family forever

Comment: @MohammadrezaJahankhah +1 post it as an aswer, it might be useful for future visitors

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;`

Here's the MSDN documentation on it: [HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowwritestreambuffering.aspx)

Here's a note from that page:

> Setting AllowWriteStreamBuffering to true might cause performance
>   problems when uploading large datasets because the data buffer could
>   use all available memory.

Comment: i use request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false; but it cant fix the problem and my program increase memory yet

Comment: Where do you set it? I believe it needs to be before you get the request stream. If you are doing that, then you will probably run a memory profiler to find out what is using up all the memory.